# application.json configuration in Spring Boot application

Tags: json, spring-boot

Is there a way to use **application.json** file in Spring Boot the same way as *[application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)* and *[application.yml](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml)* for configuration?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The official spring documentation does not say there is as of spring boot 1.5.1 RELEASE.
[Properties & Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html)
The only JSON related wording in Properties & configuration section is:

> YAML is a superset of JSON and as such is a very convenient syntax for storing external properties in a hierarchical format